# How can I quickly clear all cells containing only non-printable characters using VBA?

Tags: excel, removing-whitespace, vba

I regularly work with large amounts of data in Excel and one of my steps in "scrubbing" it is to find cells that only contain non-printable characters and clear them.

To clarify, my definition of a matching cell to clear is any cell that when formatted with black font would not print any ink on a sheet of paper.

This includes cells with only:

- vbNullString, the same value as this formula: =""
- Any type of space (I found out the hard way that there are many different space characters.)
- Tab
- Any type of line break
- Any other non-printing characters

**A good answer will consider:**

- Worksheets may contain hundreds of thousands of rows of Excel data and millions of cells.
- Matching cells to be cleared may contain multiple non-printing characters.
- Worksheets may contain large ranges empty ranges.
- Speed is a big factor.
- It is important to preserve non-printable characters if they are within cells that also contain printable characters.

**What I have tried:**
Here's my code so far, which saves the worksheet cell values to an array, and loops through them one by one looking for Unicode character numbers of 160 or less than or equal to 32, which covers most or all non-printable characters as far as I can tell.  It only finds cells equal to a single non-printable character (i.e. it would miss a cell containing only two spaces).  On my machine it runs through about 250,000 cells per second.

```
Public Sub EmptyAllBlankCells()

    ' Get the last row in the worksheet
    Dim maxRow As Long
    maxRow = GetMaxCell.Row

    ' Get the last column in the worksheet
    Dim MaxCol As Byte
    MaxCol = GetMaxCell.Column

    ' Create an array of all worksheet cell values.
    Dim arrData As Variant
    ReDim arrData(0 To maxRow, 0 To MaxCol)
    arrData = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(maxRow, MaxCol))

    ' Empty the contents of blank and whitespace only cells.
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim iCellText As Variant  ' or BYTE
    For iRow = 1 To UBound(arrData, 1)                  ' First array dimension is rows.
        For iCol = 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)              ' Second array dimension is columns.
            On Error Resume Next
            iCellText = AscW(arrData(iRow, iCol))
            On Error GoTo 0
            If iCellText <= 32 Or iCellText = 160 Then
                ' Cell contains only a single non-printable character.
                arrData(iRow, iCol) = Empty ' Empty the cell.
            End If
            iCellText = Empty
        Next iCol
    Next iRow


    ' Write array back to worksheet.
    Dim Destination As Range
    Set Destination = Range("A1")
    Destination.Resize(UBound(arrData, 1), UBound(arrData, 2)).Value = arrData

End Sub

Private Function GetMaxCell(Optional ByRef rng As Range = Nothing) As Range
    'Returns the last cell containing a value, or A1 if Worksheet is empty

    Const NONEMPTY As String = "*"

    If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
        Set GetMaxCell = rng.Parent.Cells(1, 1)
    Else
        Dim lRow As Range

        With rng
            Set lRow = .Cells.Find(What:=NONEMPTY, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                        After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
            If Not lRow Is Nothing Then

                Dim lCol As Range
                Set lCol = .Cells.Find(What:=NONEMPTY, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                            After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)

                Set GetMaxCell = .Parent.Cells(lRow.Row, lCol.Column)

            End If
        End With

    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an awkward question to answer because there's quite a big difference between *white space* and *non-printable* characters. White space is basically a set of 'characters' that you don't see (ie formatting, spaces, etc.) and can be removed simply with a `RegEx` expression. Non-printable characters are a much more complicated beast as they are dependent on your device (known as a `Device Context`), such as screen or printer, and on your font (some values are 'visible' in one font but not another).

If you genuinely want to access a list of printable glyphs (ie for your specific device and your specific font), then some `Windows APIs` exist which can extract that information. The key one is the `GetFontUnicodeRanges()` function. It's a fiddly function to use in VBA because it populates a type known as a GLYPHSTRUCTURE. This type contains an array of unknown dimension and, in VBA, you can't read memory into a data type of unknown size - neither can you redimension that type for a memory read once you know the size. So acquiring the data requires a kind of iterative memory copy. The code below shows you how to do it, but I should add a caveat that I'm still 32-bit, so you'd need to google these APIs to convert them to 64-bit (quite a simple task).

**Acquiring the list of printable glyphs**

At the top of your Module, paste the following APIs:

```
Private Type WCRANGE
    wcLow As Integer
    cGlyphs As Integer
End Type
Private Type GLYPHSET
    cbThis As Long
    flAccel As Long
    cGlyphsSupported As Long
    cRanges As Long
    ranges() As WCRANGE
End Type
Private Declare Function CreateDC Lib "gdi32" Alias "CreateDCA" (ByVal lpDriverName As String, ByVal lpDeviceName As String, ByVal lpOutput As String, ByVal lpInitData As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function CreateFont Lib "gdi32.dll" Alias "CreateFontA" (ByVal nHeight As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nEscapement As Long, ByVal nOrientation As Long, ByVal fnWeight As Long, ByVal fdwItalic As Long, ByVal fdwUnderline As Long, ByVal fdwStrikeOut As Long, ByVal fdwCharSet As Long, ByVal fdwOutputPrecision As Long, ByVal fdwClipPrecision As Long, ByVal fdwQuality As Long, ByVal fdwPitchAndFamily As Long, ByVal lpszFace As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SelectObject Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DeleteObject Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetFontUnicodeRanges Lib "gdi32.dll" (ByVal hDC As Long, pGLYPHSET As Any) As Long
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (pDestination As Any, pSource As Any, ByVal lByteCount As Long)
```

In the same module, paste the following function:

```
Private Function GetPrintables(fontName As String, rejects As String) As Collection
    Dim hDC As Long, hFont As Long, ret As Long, byteCount As Long
    Dim b() As Byte
    Dim i As Long, c As Long
    Dim gs As GLYPHSET
    Dim wc As WCRANGE
    Dim printables As Collection
    Dim rejectArray() As String
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim hit As Boolean


    'Create a design context and font.
    'Note: I've just used your screen context. Google if you want to use a printer.
    hDC = CreateDC("DISPLAY", vbNullString, vbNullString, ByVal 0&)
    hFont = CreateFont(0, 0, 0, 0, 400, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 Or 0, fontName)
    ret = SelectObject(hDC, hFont)

    'Find size of GLYPHSET structure.
    byteCount = GetFontUnicodeRanges(hDC, ByVal 0&)
    ReDim b(0 To byteCount - 1)
    ret = GetFontUnicodeRanges(hDC, b(0))
    'Populate first 4 items of GLYPHSET
    CopyMemory gs, b(0), LenB(gs) - LenB(wc)
    'Populate .ranges array of GLYPHSET
    ReDim gs.ranges(0 To gs.cRanges - 1)
    i = LenB(gs) - LenB(wc)
    For c = 0 To gs.cRanges - 1
        CopyMemory gs.ranges(c), b(i), LenB(wc)
        i = i + LenB(wc)
    Next

    'Delete the graphics objects
    DeleteObject hFont
    DeleteObject hDC

    'Create the list of printable glyphs
    rejectArray = Split(rejects, "|")
    Set GetPrintables = New Collection
    For c = 0 To gs.cRanges - 1
        wc = gs.ranges(c)
        For i = wc.wcLow To wc.wcLow + wc.cGlyphs - 1
            'Ignore printable glyphs in our reject list
            hit = False
            For Each v In rejectArray
                If i = CLng(v) Then
                    hit = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If Not hit Then GetPrintables.Add True, CStr(i)
        Next
    Next
End Function
```

You'll need to add your own error handling if you want it and this would include testing if the return values of the API are 0 (signifying a failed function).

**Testing your values**

I think you'd find it easier to reverse your testing rules; that's to say, rather than looking exclusively for non-printable characters try testing for the existence of any printable character. If the test resolves to true then the value should remain unchanged (according to your post). So the code, still in your module, would be:

```
Public Sub EmptyAllBlankCells()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim minCell As Range, maxCell As Range
    Dim arrData As Variant
    Dim printables As Collection
    Dim rejects As String
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, i As Long
    Dim str As String, chr As String
    Dim val As Long
    Dim hit As Boolean

    Set ws = Sheet1
    Set minCell = ws.Cells(1, 1)
    ' Get the last row in the worksheet
    Set maxCell = GetMaxCell(ws.UsedRange)

    ' Create an array of all worksheet cell values.
    arrData = ws.Range(minCell, maxCell).Value2

    'Acquire the list of printable characters.
    rejects = "&H0020|&H00A0|&H1680|&H180E|&H2000|&H2001|&H2002|&H2003|&H2004|&H2005|&H2006|&H2007|&H2008|&H2009|&H200A|&H200B|&H202F|&H205F|&H3000|&HFEFF"
    Set printables = GetPrintables(minCell.Font.Name, rejects)

    ' Empty the contents of blank and whitespace only cells.
    For r = 1 To UBound(arrData, 1)                  ' First array dimension is rows.
        For c = 1 To UBound(arrData, 2)              ' Second array dimension is columns.
            If Not IsEmpty(arrData(r, c)) Then
                str = CStr(arrData(r, c))
                hit = False
                For i = 1 To Len(str)
                    chr = Mid(str, i, 1)
                    val = AscW(chr)
                    If val < 0 Then val = 65536 + val
                    On Error Resume Next
                    hit = printables(CStr(val))
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    If hit Then Exit For
                Next
'                If Not hit Then arrData(r, c) = Empty
                If Not hit Then arrData(r, c) = arrData(r, c) & "N"
            End If
        Next
    Next

    ' Write array back to worksheet.
    ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrData, 1), UBound(arrData, 2)).Value = arrData

End Sub
```

You'll notice a variable called `rejects`. This is simply a list of printable glyphs that you still don't want - in the sample code, it's a list of unicode spaces.

**Speed**

You're right to read the data into an array, especially if they're of the magnitude you suggest in your post. To keep things working quickly, I've used a `Collection` which contains every single printable glyph and whose key is the unicode value converted to a string. It's not memory efficient but it would be relatively fast.